# How to prevent duplicate entry in registration activity with "Username already taken"

Tags: java, android

I would like to include a code such that, when a user registers a username that has already been used in my app, he/she will get a toast saying "Username is already taken".

**Register.java**

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText regEmail, regPassword;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    regEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
    regPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
}
public void OnReg(View view) {
    String strEmail = regEmail.getText().toString();
    String strPassword = regPassword.getText().toString();
    String type = "register";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, strEmail, strPassword);
}}
```

BackgroundWorker.java

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://10.93.22.231/login.php";
        String register_url = "http://10.93.22.231/register.php";
        if (type.equals("login")){
            try {
                String email = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (type.equals("register")){
            try {
                String regEmail = params[1];
                String regPassword = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regEmail,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(regPassword,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        if (result.contains("success")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php
require "conn.php";

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('$email','$password')";

if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE){
echo "Insert successful";
} else {
echo "Insert failed, please try again.";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: in onPostExecute() method you have string. you can convert it as JSONObject which should be contains your's actual message. then get that message and toast it.

Comment: `onPostExecute` what are you getting in the result..?

Comment: @jun Guo your php code not contain any user validation query or code.add validation query or code and try

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE email="'$email;

Comment: updated my answer check it

Comment: Just checked your answer. The alertDialog now appears regardless of whether the email has been used.

Comment: you have to return some data from php code . if true , the email is present . so, you just encode the message with the "User already exists" otherwise let the user to continue registration process. here, first you should validate the email id first, then iif user is not present on the database, let the user registration process continue otherwise, encode some message with "User already exists" then return that as JsonObject .

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivtyOrContext,"Username Taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey please check this code, maybe it can solve your problem. This is simple code.

```
  if (ConnectivityDetector.isConnectingToInternet(RegisterActivity.this)) {
            JSONObject jsonObjectInput = new JSONObject();

            jsonObjectInput.put(WebField.REGISTER_USER.REQUEST_USER_NAME,
                    edtUserName.getText().toString());

            String mode = "RegisterUser";

            new GetJsonWithCallBack(RegisterActivity.this, jsonObjectInput,
                    1, mode, new OnUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUpdateComplete(JSONObject jsonObject,
                                             boolean isSuccess) {

                    if (isSuccess) {

                        try {

                            if (jsonObject != null) {
                                if (jsonObject.has("userDetail")) {
                                    JSONObject jsonUserDetails = jsonObject.getJSONObject("userDetail");

                                    RegisterData regData = new RegisterData();

                                    regData.setUserName(jsonUserDetails.getString(WebField.REGISTER_USER.RESPONSE_USER_NAME));

                                    SessionManager.saveData(RegisterActivity.this, regData);

                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {

                        if (jsonObject != null) {
                            try {
                                String Status = jsonObject.getString("status");

                                String message = jsonObject.getString("message");

                                if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("User already Exists")) {
                                    GlobalMethod.showAlert(RegisterActivity.this, "User name already exists..!!");

                                } else if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("Email id already Exists")) {
                                    GlobalMethod.showAlert(RegisterActivity.this, "Email id already exists..!!");

                                } else if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("Mobile no already Exists")) {
                                    GlobalMethod.showAlert(RegisterActivity.this, "Mobile no already exists..!!");

                                } else {
                                    GlobalMethod.showAlert(RegisterActivity.this, jsonObject.getString("message"));
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).execute();
        } else {
            AlertDialogUtility.showInternetAlert(RegisterActivity.this);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

on Post execute you can do some thing like this

also at the server level if the username already exists you should not save the record instead of that you should pass the value that username already exists

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result.contains("success")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context,result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
 @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   alertDialog.setMessage(result);
   if (result.contains("success")) {
       JSONObject json= new JSONObject(result);
        if(json.has("message"){
        String message=json.getString("message");
        Toast.makeText(ctx,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
       Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
       context.startActivity(intent);
   } else {
       alertDialog.show();
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

User validation query

```
 $mysql_qry="SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";

 if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE){
 }else{}
```

Comment: Tried it, results are the same, app brings me to the MainActivity even though I registered with the same email address.